# File opened by Gedit from mounted flash drive in READ ONLY mode

Tags: gedit

I just mounted a flash drive, and have ran `sudo mount -o remount,exec /home/my_name/folder_name`.

However, when I open a text file from my mounted flash drive, gedit tells me that it is in READ ONLY mode. How do I enable editing?

Thank you.

SOLUTION: I was able to fix my problem by opening Gedit with the `gksu` prefix

Comment: Does your flash drive have a read-only switch somewhere ?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo mount -o remount,rw /home/my_name/folder_name`? If it fails please also include the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50`.